How can a problem with cases be represented formally?
For example, if there are two men A & B.
A says

Both of us always tell the truth

B says

A always lies

Edit: A and B either always tell the truth or lie.
What I know that this can be solved by using cases.
So, in case we assume A is telling the truth, then B is also telling the truth which implies that A is telling a lie which is a contradiction.
On the hand in case we assume A is telling a lie, which means B can be either telling the truth or lying.
So if we assume B to be telling the truth, then there is no contradiction. On the other than there is contradiction if we assume otherwise.
So how can all of these steps be represented formally? I was thinking first of using T(x) and L(x) for telling truth or a lie respectively. But I have no idea how to proceed further.
P.S: I am a total beginner in Logic and I have not done anything similar either. All I know are the basic examples where sentences are represented by P and Q and have proved them using truth tables.

Well, I agree that $A$ can not be telling the truth, but I don't see how you can conclude anything about $B$.  It's possible that $B$ is telling the truth, but it is also possible that $B$ is lying...Suppose that $A$ lies sometimes but not always.  Then $B$ is lying (about the "always").   If you change $B's$ claim to "$A$ sometimes lies" then I agree that $B$ must be telling the truth (as we have an instance of $A$ lying).  I am trusting here that we are to assume that $A,B$ have full and accurate knowledge.  That is, we are are not allowing for "honest mistake" as an option.

@lulu A and B either always tell the truth or lie I think. Just an example, may be I got it wrong somewhere. But what I wanted to know is not what the solution is, but rather how to represent it. Thanks for pointing it out BTW.

A simple way to formalise this problem is to assume that $A$ and $B$ are propositions such that $A \iff (A \land B)$ and $B \iff \neg A$, and then you can show that e.g. $A \implies B$ and $B \implies \neg A$, hence $\neg A$.

@NaïmFavier thanks, but a noob question, why biconditional instead of implication?

@GrandeKnight $B$ says exactly $\neg A$, in the sense that if $\neg A$ is true then $B$ is telling the truth. One could also use the equivalence symbol $A \equiv \neg B$.

@TankutBeygu Thanks, so in my case, will the statements be A, B, ¬A and ¬B?

@NaïmFavier Sorry for misspelling your name earlier, and thanks for the correction.

Naïm Favier's comment is spot-on.
First: A person who always tells the truth is called a "knight".  It's quicker to say and to understand "$A$ is a knight" than to say or understand "$A$ is a person who always tells the truth."
A person who always lies is a called a knave.   You've told us that each of $A$ and $B$ is either a knight or a knave.
Suppose some person $P$ asserts some claim $x$, such as "it is raining" or "$Q$ is a knave".
Then  that claim $x$ is true if $P$ is a knight, because knights only say true things.
And also, that claim $x$ is true only if $P$ is a knight, because if $P$ isn't a knight then $P$ is a knave, knaves only say false things, $P$ said $x$, so $x$ is false.
(You asked in the comment "why biconditional instead of implication", and this is why.  The biconditional is because $A$ is either a knight or a knave.  If $P$ might be a normal person who sometimes lies and sometimes truths, then the biconditional would be an implication instead.)
So in general:
$$\text{$A$ says $x$}$$
can be understood to mean
$$\text{$x$ is true if and only if $A$ is a knight}.$$
You wanted to write "$T(x)$" to mean that $x$ is true.  This is unnecessary. When we want to assert that $x$ is true, we don't need a special notation because that's what "$x$" itself asserts already.  For example, if I want to say that it's true that snow is white, I don't need to say something special like  "$T(\text{snow is white})$".  I just say "$\text{snow is white}$".   It's the same thing.  To claim that snow is white is the same as to claim that it's true that snow is white.
Your "$L(x)$" to mean that $x$ is a lie is more useful.  The standard logic notation for that is "$\lnot x$".
A more useful notation would be to write "$N(P)$" to mean that person $P$ is a knight.  We wouldn't need a special "$V(P)$" notation to mean that $P$ is a knave.  Everyone is either a knight or a knave, so $V(P)$ is the same as $\lnot N(P)$: a person $P$ is a knave if and only if it's false that $P$ is a knight.
But we don't actually use the $N(P)$ notation because it's simpler  to abbreviate it away. We just agree  that "$P$"  will represent the statement that person $P$ is a knight.  This is abusing the notation a little bit: sometimes "$P$" means the person $P$, and sometimes it means that statement that person $P$ is a knight.  In practice this is not confusing, once you are prepared for it. The notation "$\lnot P$" now means that it's false that $P$ is a knight, so that's how we write "$P$ is a knave".
You asked "how can all of these steps be represented formally?"  We're ready to do go ahead.  Suppose
$$\text{person $P$ says $x$}$$
Following Naïm Favier's suggestion we can convert this into
$$ \text{$x$ is true if and only if person $P$ is a knight}$$
or in symbols:
$$x\iff P$$
where "$P$" now abbreviates "person $P$ is a knight".
In your actual problem, you have:

A says "$A$ and $B$ are both knights"
B says "$A$ is a knave"

So in symbols,

$(A\land B) \iff A $
$(\lnot A) \iff B$

("$\land$" has been the standard symbol for "and" since the 1930s, so you may as well learn it now.)
At this point the problem can be solved in many ways.
One way is synthetically:  (2) tells us that $A$ and and $B$ are opposite: $A$ is true if and only if $B$ is false.  But $A\land B$ means that $A$ and $B$ are both true, so it must be false.   And since (1) tells us $A$ is true if and only if $A\land B$ is, $A$ must also be false.  Since $A$ and $B$ are opposite, $B$ must be true.  So person $A$ is a knave and person $B$ is a knight.
Another way to solve this is with a so-called "truth table":
$$\begin{array}{cc||cc|cc}
A & B & A\land B & \lnot A & {1?\atop (A\land B = A)} & 2?\atop(\lnot A = B) \\ \hline
T & T & T & F & ✅&❌ \\
T & F & F & F & ❌&✅ \\
F & T & F & T & ✅&✅ \\
F & F & F & T & ✅&❌ \\
\end{array}
$$
There are four possibilities for the ways $A$ and $B$ can be true or false, and this lists them all (first two columns), along with the corresponding values for person $A$ and person $B$'s claims (next two columns).  The last two columns are the conditions from the problem statement, connecting what each person said with who they are.
Condition (1) tells us we must have $A\land B = A$, which rules out row 2.  Condition (2) tells us we must have $\lnot A = B$, which rules out rows 1 and 4.  So the only consistent possibility is row 3: person $A$ is a knave and $B$ is a knight.
